# Chrome extension code not interacting with website correctly

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, google-chrome-extension, css-selectors, manifest.json

I'm working on a Chrome extension with the objective of automatically testing and applying discount codes on a specific website. https://order.papaginos.com/1126/dorchester-papa-ginos

The goal is to iterate through numbers from 1 to 10000, input each number into a text field on the website (discount codes when order), and then click the "REDEEM" button. If the code is valid, I want to store it and move on to the next code. If the code is not valid, I want to clear the input field and move on to the next code.

I've created the necessary components, including the manifest.json, background.js, content.js, popup.html, and popup.js files. However, the extension doesn't seem to be interacting with the website as intended. When I load the website and click the "Apply Codes" button in the popup, nothing happens in the input field, and there's no interaction with the website.

I suspect the issue might be related to incorrect selectors for the input field and the "REDEEM" button. I've tried to use selectors based on the data-v-58a62846 attribute and other attributes, but it doesn't seem to work.

- Verified that the extension is properly loaded and active.
- Checked if the extension has the required permissions in the manifest.json.
- Examined the content.js code to ensure that the interaction logic is implemented correctly.
- Tested different selectors for the input field and "REDEEM" button in the content.js file.

```
// manifest.json
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Discount Code Tester",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Automatically test and apply discount codes on a website.",
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "storage"
  ],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://order.papaginos.com/1126/dorchester-papa-ginos"],
      "js": ["content.js"],
      "run_at": "document_end"
    }
  ]
}

// background.js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
  if (request.action === 'getValidCodes') {
    chrome.storage.local.get('validCodes', (result) => {
      sendResponse({ validCodes: result.validCodes || [] });
    });
  }
  return true; // Indicates that we will send a response asynchronously
});

// content.js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    const codesToTry = Array.from({ length: 10000 }, (_, i) => (i + 1).toString());
  
    const inputField = document.querySelector('input[data-v-58a62846][type="text"]');
    const applyButton = document.querySelector('button[data-v-58a62846]:contains("REDEEM")');
  
    let currentIndex = 0;
  
    function applyCode(code) {
      inputField.value = code;
    
      // Find the REDEEM button and click it
      if (applyButton) {
        applyButton.click();
        
        setTimeout(() => {
          const pageContentBefore = document.documentElement.innerHTML;
          
          setTimeout(() => {
            const pageContentAfter = document.documentElement.innerHTML;
            
            if (pageContentBefore !== pageContentAfter) {
              // Content has changed, indicating a successful discount code application
              // Notify the background script to store the valid code
              chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ action: 'storeValidCode', code: code });
            } else {
              // Code was not valid, clear the input field
              inputField.value = '';
            }
    
            // Continue to the next code
            currentIndex++;
            tryNextCode();
          }, 1000); // Wait 1 second before comparing content after
        }, 1000); // Wait 1 second before clicking the REDEEM button
      } else {
        // Redeem button not found, move to the next code
        currentIndex++;
        tryNextCode();
      }
    }
  
    function tryNextCode() {
      if (currentIndex < codesToTry.length) {
        applyCode(codesToTry[currentIndex]);
      }
    }
  
    // Button click event listener
    applyButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
      tryNextCode();
    });
  });
  
// popup.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Discount Code Results</title>
  <style>
    body {
      width: 200px;
      padding: 10px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Discount Code Results</h1>
  <ul id="validCodesList"></ul>
  
  <!-- Add a button to trigger the script -->
  <button id="applyCodesButton">Apply Codes</button>
  
  <script src="popup.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

// popup.js

// Function to initiate the code application on the content script
function applyCodes() {
  chrome.scripting.executeScript({
    target: { tabId: getCurrentTabId() },
    function: startCodeApplication
  });
}

// Get the ID of the currently active tab
function getCurrentTabId() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, (tabs) => {
      resolve(tabs[0].id);
    });
  });
}

// Attach an event listener to the "Apply Codes" button
document.getElementById('applyCodesButton').addEventListener('click', applyCodes);

// Fetch and display valid codes in the popup
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ action: 'getValidCodes' }, (response) => {
  const validCodesList = document.getElementById('validCodesList');

  if (response.validCodes && response.validCodes.length > 0) {
    response.validCodes.forEach((code) => {
      const listItem = document.createElement('li');
      listItem.textContent = code;
      validCodesList.appendChild(listItem);
    });
  } else {
    const listItem = document.createElement('li');
    listItem.textContent = 'No valid codes stored yet.';
    validCodesList.appendChild(listItem);
  }
});

The objective of my code: write a chrome extension code that tries and applies every number from 1 to 10000 on a website. if the code is not valid, then remove the code and try the next. if the code is valid, then write down what the discount code is and store it, then remove the code
```

Comment: 1) Try the deprecated document.execCommand, [example](/a/57900849). 2) Remove document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded' and just run the code immediately. Your code already runs at DOMContentLoaded as specified in manifest.json. 3) You can use devtools to debug your content script interactively by placing breakpoints and step-executing through the code. Note that the popup is a separate window so it has its own separate devtools: right-click inside the popup and select "inspect" in the menu. 4) No need for the background script, you can use chrome.storage directly.